# SFML pollEvent for 1.6 (what is the equivalent)

Tags: c++, sfml

http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php

There is no pollEvent for a render window according to the 1.6 documentation

I am wondering what the equivalent is

http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Window.php

it pops the event on top of the events stack and returns it

thank you

[:

Answer (score 1):

It is GetEvent() apparently! O: